# What are the differences between using self.add_error() and raising a ValidationError()?

Tags: django, django-errors

You can throw a validation error in 2 ways. The first is with `self.add_error()` and the second with `raise ValidationError()`.

I've read that when you use `self.add_error('field1','description here')` then `field1` is also automatically removed from the `cleaned_data` list and i assume a ValidationError object is also added to the `self.errors` list, is this correct?

But what happens when you don't choose to use `self.add_error` and opt for using `raise ValidationError`  instead? Is this object also automatically added to the `errors` list behind the scenes? And how would you display this error message as caption under the correct invalid field?

Thank you

Comment: There can be multiple errors. If you raise a validation error, the control flow for that methods stops.

Comment: what do you mean by that? That the user gets redirected to an error page? Because i wouldn't want that to happen. I want the form with any values in it to be returned, along with some error messages under the relevant fields. Can this only be done with `the add_error()` method? If so, in what cases would you want to use  a ValidationError over the `errors` list then?

Comment: no, raising a ValidationError stops the flow for that particular method. So if you raise a ValidationError in `clean()`, any code that you **write in that method** coming after that won't run. In that case you might consider `add_error()`. If you raise ValidationError in `clean_<some_field>()` it might make sense to raise ValidationError since you might not want to go into other checks if the first check fails already. The ValidationErrors raised are shown together in the `form.errors`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you raise an error, the control flow of that method, and callers of that method stops, until there is a method that has span a `try`-`except` over that, and catches the exception accordingly.

But sometimes a field might contain *multiple* errors. For example if you have a password, you might want to add errors because it is too short, does not contain a digit, a lowercase, and/or upppercase.

Then you thus can implement this with:

```
def clean_password(self):
    pwd = self.cleaned_data['password']
    if len(pwd) < 10:
        self.add_error('password', 'The password is too short.')
    if not any(c.isupper() for c in pwd):
        self.add_error('password', 'The password should contain an uppercase character.')
    if not any(c.islower() for c in pwd):
        self.add_error('password', 'The password should contain an lowercase character.')
    if not any(c.isdigit() for c in pwd):
        self.add_error('password', 'The password should contain an digit.')
    return pwd
```

If you would raise a `ValidationError` for one of these, it can not add *mutliple* problems that a password might have.

You can however pass a list of errors to a `ValidationError` data constructor, hence you can use the two interchangeable.

Comment: but isn't another difference that with the add_errors method you can also indicate which field caused the error (like you show in your example)? Or can you do something similar with `ValidationError()`? In the django documentation i can only see that you can add a code and an error message to the ValidationError constructor, and also params.

Comment: ValidationError() You can also specify the field: ValidationError(({field:['Message of Error 1',]}), code='error1')